# How to click on the verification message and button within https://www.tempinbox.xyz/mailbox/username@domain.name using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wanted to go to a page by clicking a button. First i needed to click on the mail, and then click on "this is me"

```
time.sleep(10)
second_tab = webdriver.Chrome()
second_tab.get("https://www.tempinbox.xyz/mailbox/fohtek@fitschool.be")
clickmails= second_tab.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]").click()
time.sleep(5)
clickverilink=second_tab.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'This is me!')]").click()
```

But for some reason, whenever I click this, it redirects me to a random ad page. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Probably it will be better if you get the URL from that button and then use ```driver.get(<button URL>)```

Comment: nah it doesnt solve the problem since the url changes everytime. so how can i extract url from a button?

Comment: clickverilink= second_tab.find_element_by_link_text('This is me!').click() evn this fails to work

Comment: Instead of time.sleep try using the expected conditions of WebDriverWait

```WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'This is me!')]")))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click first on the on the *mail-item* with text as **Activate your Wattpad account** and then to click on <kbd>This is me!</kbd> button you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.tempinbox.xyz/mailbox/fohtek@fitschool.be")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#mails div.message"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.container#container table.row#row2 tbody td#maincontent a"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.tempinbox.xyz/mailbox/fohtek@fitschool.be")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='mails']//div[@class='message']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='container' and @id='container']//table[@class='row' and @id='row2']//tbody//td[@id='maincontent']//a[contains(., 'This is me!')]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: wattpad_activation]

Comment: this is me button still not clicking

Comment: @Legend_recalls _XPath_ or _CssSelector_?

Comment: tried both but still doesnt work...https://www.semrush.com/ this domain is opening

Comment: @Legend_recalls Checkout the answer update and let me know the results